# How to I use regular expressions to match a substring?

Tags: r, regex

I want to change the rownames of `cov_stats`, such that it contains a substring of the `FileName` column values. I only want to retain the string that begins with "SRR" followed by 8 digits (e.g., SRR18826803).

```
cov_list <- list.files(path="./stats/", full.names=T) 
cov_stats <- rbindlist(sapply(cov_list, fread, simplify=F), use.names=T, idcol="FileName")
rownames(cov_stats) <- gsub("^\.\/\SRR*_\stats.\txt", "SRR*", cov_stats[["FileName"]])
```

Second attempt

```
rownames(cov_stats) <- gsub("^SRR[:digit:]*", "", cov_stats[["FileName"]])
```

Original strings

```
> cov_stats[["FileName"]]
 [1] "./stats/SRR18826803_stats.txt" "./stats/SRR18826804_stats.txt"
 [3] "./stats/SRR18826805_stats.txt" "./stats/SRR18826806_stats.txt"
 [5] "./stats/SRR18826807_stats.txt" "./stats/SRR18826808_stats.txt"
```

Desired substring output

```
 [1] "SRR18826803" "SRR18826804"
 [3] "SRR18826805" "SRR18826806"
 [5] "SRR18826807" "SRR18826808"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
library(stringr)

stringr::str_extract(cov_stats[["FileName"]], "SRR.{0,8}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
rownames(cov_stats) <- sub("^\\./stats/(SRR\\d{8}).*", "\\1", cov_stats[["FileName"]])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Mi3OFU/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\./stats/` - `./stats/` string
- `(SRR\d{8})` - Group 1 (`\1`): `SRR` string and then eight digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string till its end.

Note that `sub` is used (not `gsub`) because there is only one expected replacement operation in the input string (since the regex matches the whole string).

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/Srg8MG):

```r
cov_stats <- c("./stats/SRR18826803_stats.txt", "./stats/SRR18826804_stats.txt", "./stats/SRR18826805_stats.txt", "./stats/SRR18826806_stats.txt", "./stats/SRR18826807_stats.txt")
sub("^\\./stats/(SRR\\d{8}).*", "\\1", cov_stats)
## => [1] "SRR18826803" "SRR18826804" "SRR18826805" "SRR18826806" "SRR18826807"
```

An equivalent extraction `stringr` approach:

```r
library(stringr)
rownames(cov_stats) <- str_extract(cov_stats[["FileName"]], "SRR\\d{8}")
```